# List Item sending an email on ItemUpdated previous confirmation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list, event-receivers, email

I'm working on a Sharepoint 2010 List trying to send an email with a custom Even Receiver, on Item Updated.

The List Item has to send an email when some fields are filled, other email when other fields are filled and finally one email more when a chekbox field is selected. I will control that in the Event Receiver.

But the important thing is that before sending any email the user, who has edited the list item, has to agree. I need something like javascript window.confirm(), asking the user: "Are you sure you want send an email to user2@domain.com?"

Thank you very much

Edit:
After some researching, I think the only way is to have a hidden field (i.e. checkbox not showed in the Edit Form) and before reach the server side (Event Receiver) throw a client side script (Javascript) to ask the question to the user, and activate or not the hidden field depending on his answer. But, I've never work in Sharepoint with client script :(

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Showing a javascript alert to the user and getting a result from this would not be straightforward. For a workaround, You can add a checkbox in your list column saying "Send Email" . So if it is checked you can send email to other people.

Comment: Thanks Aanchal, it's a good idea, but it's not enough for me. The user could forget it or select the wrong checkbox. I need it do it automatically, but with confirmation. Some other idea?

Comment: You can create some mandatory column in which your has to fill data about it. Out-of-the-box i don't think there is any option.